# Finding Index bounds for a recursive subsequence

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, sum, divide-and-conquer

I have a quick question about a maximum subsequence algorithm that uses divide and conquer shown below:

```
private static int maxSum3Recursive(int[] a, int left, int right)
{ 

    if (left == right)
    {
        if (a[left] > 0)
        {

            return a[left];
        }
        else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    int center = (left + right) / 2;
    int maxLeftSum = maxSum3Recursive(a, left, center);
    int maxRightSum = maxSum3Recursive(a, center + 1, right); 

    int maxLeftBorderSum = 0;
    int leftBorderSum = 0;
    for (int i = center; i >= left; i--)
    {
        leftBorderSum += a[i];
        if (leftBorderSum > maxLeftBorderSum)
        {
            maxLeftBorderSum = leftBorderSum;


        }
    }

    int maxRightBorderSum = 0;
    int rightBorderSum = 0;
    for (int i = center + 1; i <= right; i++)
    {
        rightBorderSum += a[i];
        if (rightBorderSum > maxRightBorderSum)
        {
            maxRightBorderSum = rightBorderSum;


        }
    }


    return Math.max(maxLeftSum, Math.max(maxRightSum, maxLeftBorderSum + maxRightBorderSum));
}
```

The algorithm works as expected and gives me the maximum sum, however, I'm having trouble finding the start and end index for the bounds for the maximum. For example, let's say we have an array: {5, -5, 2, 9}. The sum would be 2 + 9 = 11 and index would be [2 - 3] since the sum has to be consecutive. In other words, we can't just use 5 and 9 to make 14 because they are not next to each other.

I would appreciate any help figuring out the indexes.

Comment: You will have to not only return info of the max sum, but also of the indexes where it happens to be able to propagate back the indexes to your original call. So use either a class or a structure that lets you store more than 1 element